# Find Deleted Question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked a question on stackoverflow but have voted to delete it. Now I can't find it under questions on my profile page and I also searched for the title but couldn't find it. How can I find this question?

Comment: Uh, you deleted it. What did you expect?

Comment: thanks genius! your comment was very insightful!

Comment: @clawson there are too many "genius" like Josh on this Web Site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92254/how-can-i-find-a-deleted-question and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one?
[Form.ShowDialog() does not show form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672482/showdialog-wont-run)

Generally deleted posts only show if you have 10k+ rep; I'm a bit surprised it doesn't show your *own* deleted questions on your profile, though, and you *might* find you can't get back in. If you have problems, let me know; and do you a: want it undeleted, or b: want a copy of the original text.

Comment: when I follow that link I get "Page Not Found" ... but yes that looks like the right title. How do you search for that? How can I view this page?

Comment: Well yes, i can't see my own deleted question. I would like to undelete it, because I found a may to make it work and thought the question was a bit silly, but then when I think I realised what was the actual problem I thought it might be appropriate to share. But looks like it doesn't want me to do that :-(

Comment: @clawson The question has been undeleted.

Comment: @marc: i recall hitting a threshold where i could suddenly see my own deleted questions.  no idea where it is (3k? 5k? less? more?), but i'm pretty sure it was before i hit 10k and could see others' deleted posts.

Comment: @Marc: i should also like to see my deleted questions/answers. Why not extend the search functionality with an appropriate parameter, for example: `user:me is:question flag:deleted`?

Comment: @Marc: I'm looking for a question I asked about whether `UIApplication` should inherit from `UIResponder` or `NSObject`. I asked to delete it because I thought I might have been breaking the Apple Developer NDA. But now, I found that I can site [UIResponder Class Reference](http://j.mp/q5VPZ8) instead of the XCode 4.2 template. Would you please undelete this question so I can edit it? Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanSampson I just deleted my question titled something like: "objectsPassingTest: vs. filteredSetUsingPredicate:" Would you please un-delete that question and the one mentioned in my comment above? Thanks! :)

Comment: @MattDiPasquale http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893221/why-does-appdelegate-inherit-from-uiresponder and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372953/objectspassingtest-vs-filteredsetusingpredicate undeleted

Comment: @MarcGravell: I am looking for my deleted questions(deleted by me or otherwise). Please. There is one specific question I asked about `WPF Datagrid DateTime Colum Binding` which I can't find link to even though I have 10k+ rep. Please Undelete it.

Comment: @Nikhil this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258131/how-to-set-wpf-datagrid-header-horizontal-alignment-when-autogeneratecolumns-tr

Comment: @MarcGravell: No not this one. Another one. `WPF Databinding string format for DateTime Column`. BTW is there a query to run in data.stackexchange to find only deleted questions. I tried `SELECT *
FROM Posts WHERE OwnerUserId = 1011959` but it shows all question other than deleted ones.

Comment: @Nikhil this one, then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032285/format-datagrid-datetime-column-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes this one. Thanks