# How can I find a deleted question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, deleted-questions

Yesterday I commented some question as duplicate. I can't find the question now so I guess it is deleted. I would like to check who has deleted the question (I have 10k+ rep). I don't see the comments to the question in my activity and I even don't see the question in [OP's activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289246/naor?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_posts). Can I find the question somehow?

When somebody starts voting for closing the question it should not be a reason for OP to delete the question.

**Edit:**

Well it looks like there is currently no way so I'm changing this to feature request. What about modifying advanced search functionality to be able to filter question by state? Something that would allow users with enough privileges to search for deleted questions if they need to or show all deleted questions and answers from selected user? I would always be able to use something like:

```
user:me deleted:1
```

but only users with 10k+ will be allowed searching deleted questions (and answers) of other users. Default value will be 0.

Comment: If it was deleted recently, you can view the recently deleted questions in the mod tools [delete tab](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete) under the Recently Deleted section.  Currently I see deleted questions that go as far as 4 hours ago.

Comment: @Jeff: Really? I currently only see posts back to an hour after expanding the Recently Deleted section. Not all that helpful, as I usually take breaks from the site that are longer than hour. (Most days. When I have to.)

Comment: @Cody: Ah I was afraid of that.  It would seem that it is limited to ~45 deleted questions in the page (meaning there was a fair amount of deletions since I commented).  And since there's no paging to go back further... then well... yeah.

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah, upon further inspection, it looks like Jeff Atwood just spent some quality time with the flag queue. ;-)

Comment: try searching your browser's history :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). [status-declined, heavily.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297#53297) (Not that I understand Jeff's reasoning, I'm only the messenger here.) And by the way, at 10k, you still can't search for deleted questions, only see them if you know the URL. Try Google.

Answer (score 3):

> Yesterday I commented some question as duplicate.

I assume that means you also voted to close it as a duplicate. In that case, since you have 10k reputation, you can find the question in [your profile, under close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure). (Users with less than 10k reputation will only see close votes on non-deleted questions.) Here is an excerpt from my history, the question is clearly visible as being a duplicate:

[image]

(Though there might be cases where the question is closed for another reason, or the author decides to delete it before it gets closed. In those cases, I hope you'll recognize the title and/or remember around what time you voted to close the question.)

Comment: Even though the user still needs 10K rep, searching deleted posts (questions and answers)  also works if they were previously flagged, followed or bookmarked.

Answer (score 2):

This is in place, but the option is only available to moderators.