# Recover a deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I remember asking a question on Stack Overflow and deleting it a long while back (more than 60 days ago) and I'm trying to recover it, but I don't know how. I read that users with high enough reputation can access deleted questions but mine is low.

So, how can I recover my question while

- I have no link to the question
- don't have high reputation
- The question was deleted more than 60 days ago
- can't find the post using the reputation tab

?

Comment: Is your browser's history no help?

Comment: @RobertLongson Over that period of time, no.  Browser history will be cleared, inevitably, at some point.

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried searching it but found nothing unfortunately

Comment: @Ollie well my browser history goes back 1 year. That's the default for Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson zowee...

Comment: This one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087375/why-is-maketrans-a-method

Comment: Well, mods can search your deleted posts from all time.  You can ask them to do it, or, if you have 10K, you can use the "deleted:1" operator.

Comment: This is why FRs like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360939/allow-all-users-to-use-the-deleted1-operator-to-find-their-own-deleted-posts) one exist...

Comment: Related, possible dupes: [How can I find a deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92254/) [Find Deleted Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47204/) [My question got deleted at Stack Overflow, can I still find it somehow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108344/) etc

Comment: You should be able to find it with the trick I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel I checked stackoverflow and the reputation changes history showed nothing, but a mod managed to find my question.

Comment: @Catija Yes this is it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HyperDimensionalBeing that might be because you had only 1 reputation when you posted that. Still, I'd expect the downvote would show in your reputation history, just like this one on Meta.SE (I've undone that vote meanwhile): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxzsb.png I guess that needs a developer to confirm.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To find a post of yours that has been deleted when

- You have low karma
- deleted the post long ago
- don't have a link for the post
- can't find the post using the reputation history trick

Just ask a mod

Comment: You can always see anything you posted on- so the lack of link is the main issue